# how to make a splitview menu on winjs

Tags: javascript, html, win-universal-app, winjs

I am trying to make a universal app by javascript. I tried a sample on msdn website but the "nav-commands" class is not showing when you open the splitview. I use closedDisplayMode = 'none'.

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="header">
        <button class="win-splitviewpanetoggle"
                data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SplitViewPaneToggle"
                data-win-options="{ splitView: select('.splitView') }"></button>

    </div>
    <div class="splitView" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SplitView"
         data-win-options="{ closedDisplayMode :'none' , openedDisplayMode : 'inline'}">
        <!-- Pane area -->
        <div><div class="header">
                 <div class="nav-commands">
                     <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SplitViewCommand" data-win-options="{ label: 'Home', icon: 'home'}"></div>
                     <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SplitViewCommand" data-win-options="{ label: 'Favorite', icon: 'favorite'}"></div>
                     <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SplitViewCommand" data-win-options="{ label: 'Settings', icon: 'settings'}"></div>

                 </div>  </div>
```

```
        <!-- Content area -->
        <div class="contenttext" id="clock"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using this code which I found from http://try.buildwinjs.com/playground/ .
But when I use the application the nac-commands are not shown it just shows splitview pane

Comment: Please post what you tried, what are you trying to achieve and what is stopping you from achieving it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using WinJS project template in VS. The newest WinJS project template in VS use WinJS 4.0.1. And for that version there is no `WinJS.UI.SplitViewCommand` Control.

> [NavBarCommand is no longer available for use as of Windows Library for JavaScript (WinJS) 4.2. Instead, use SplitViewCommand. ]

See [WinJS.UI.NavBarCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301859.aspx).

So you can use `WinJS.UI.NavBarCommand` instead.

Or you can download the newest WinJS from [here](http://try.buildwinjs.com/download/GetWinJS/). Replace the WinJS library in your project, then edit the `<script>` and `<link>` tags to reference the new library in the index.html file.

Comment: I am using winjs template from VS 2015 and I copied this code from latest website for winjs which gives output for windows 10 and the class is nav-commands otherwise data-win-controls = "WinJS.UI.SplitViewCommand".  ......BTW thanks for answer